# Como se publica un webservice con certificados SSL en IIS y como puedo despues consumirlo en VS2015?

Tags: webservice, visual-studio-2015, iis, ssl, certificado-ssl

tengo un WebService que publique localmente en el IIS con certificados SSL generados localmente usando Makecert.exe. Desde el navegador lo puedo ver y usar (el navegador me pide el certificado de cliente, se lo envio y funciona, eso esta bien, es lo buscado). El problema viene al intentar acceder a el por medio de una pagina cliente, en el VS2015 no me reconoce al servicio como tal.

Este es el error que me aparece en VS2015

> There was an error downloading 'https://localhost/WScompanyname/CompanyNamemockupWS.asmx/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

[image: Este es el error que me aparece en VS2015]

Alguien sabe como consumir este WebService o publicarlo de otra manera para hacerlo accesible?

Comment: a que te refieres exactamente con "acceder a el con una página cliente"?

Comment: Estoy creando una pagina web que consume dicho WS. En resumen, la web "cliente" tendria que tener una referencia al Web Service, el cual tiene que pedir un certificado SSL para comunicarse. El problema viene cuando intento agregar la refrencia de servicio de la "pagina cliente" hacia el Web Service que esta alojado en IIS (configurado para Requerir Certificado SSL).